# What is a "marker-matched" plasmid?

Tags: genetics, experimental-design, plasmids, yeast, experimental

I see this term used a lot in papers and have trouble understanding it. From what I have gleaned it seems they are used during control experiments, perhaps with the goal of making the control plasmids as similar as possible to the experimental ones to limit confounding variables?

Here is an example from I paper I've been trying to understand.

"Cells containing an ARS1 plasmid, or a marker-matched ARS-CEN plasmid, were subjected to life span analysis." - [David Sinclair & Lenny Guarente, 1997](https://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(00)80493-6?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0092867400804936%3Fshowall%3Dtrue#secd11446259e381)

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is where a control plasmid is used - this is usually an empty vector or a non-target vector with the same "marker" on the plasmid.

The marker is often one that is either used for purification of a resulting protein (e.g. [His](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhistidine-tag), [GST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutathione_S-transferase#GST-tags_and_the_GST_pull-down_assay) etc) or immuno-detection ([FLAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAG-tag), [HA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HA-tag) etc (these can also be used for purification, as can His and GST for immuno-detection)) or fluorescent ([GFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_fluorescent_protein) etc).

In addition and as per comment from @MaximillianPress markers can also be selectable, so used to ensure that the plasmid is maintained in the cells and that all cells contain the plasmid. This is often done through expression of a marker that confers resistance to an antibiotic such as ampicillin for bacteria or geneticin for mammalian cells. In yeast nutrient deficient media can be used and the yeast will only grow if they contain a plasmid that allows metabolism or production of an essential compound (e.g [URA gene for Uracil production](https://blog.addgene.org/plasmids-101-yeast-vectors)).

Comment: I would actually expect that the marker be a yeast selectable marker, such as an auxotrophy marker like the _URA3_ / _KANMX_, that can be used to select the plasmid on dropout or antibiotic plates.

Comment: @MaximilianPress good point - I don't use selective markers very often, so I forgot about them. I'll edit that in.